# blank page or KeyError in preview Wagtail 1.10.1

Tags: django, wagtail

I just upgraded to Wagtail 1.10.1 and the preview shows only a blank page. When I force the preview by appending preview/ to the edit URL, then I get a server error. It all works just fine on my development and staging sites, so I also need some help tracking down where the error might be.

Internal Server Error: /admin/pages/81/edit/preview/

KeyError at /admin/pages/81/edit/preview/
'wagtail-preview-81'

Django Version: 1.11.1
Python Executable: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
Python Version: 3.5.2

I've been doing only minimal upgrades for a few months, so it's possible I missed something in a previous upgrade that used to work but that now I need to fix (although why it would work in the dev and staging sites but not the real one puzzles me); any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Are you sure you're running Wagtail 1.10.1 rather than 1.10? This looks a lot like a bug that was introduced in 1.10 and fixed in 1.10.1 (http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.10.1/releases/1.10.1.html).

Comment: Running pip freeze tells me it's wagtail==1.10.1

Comment: Can you update your question to include the full traceback of the error, please?

Comment: It turns out the full browser refresh + cache clearing repeated a couple of times did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refresh your browser cache in the edit page (`Ctrl + F5`) then click again on preview.

The issue is that the admin Javascript changed, but Wagtail no longer compresses its assets, so your browser cached the previous version of the Javascript file. So preview data is not correctly sent to the server, and it’s therefore unable to retrieve it when displaying the preview.

You can avoid such issues in the future by compressing admin assets.

Comment: That worked, but I had to clear the cache more than once along with refreshing the browser. Once was not enough for some reason.